# How do I build objcgen tool for .Net Embedding (Github Embeddinator-4000)?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono-embedding

5TH ATTEMPT (March 24, 2020)...

My steps to get it to build on a Mac...

```
1.  Clone github > Embeddinator-4000
git clone https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000.git

2. cd into the cloned dir

3. Install other stuff:
git submodule update --recursive --init

4. Build objcgen
cd objcgen
make
```

This gets "0 Errors" but "No shellcheck tool found" for which I cannot find a resolution.

And I can't get objcgen to run with the C# recommended example:

```
cd ~/Projects/hello-from-csharp
objcgen ~/Projects/hello-from-csharp/hello-from-csharp/bin/Debug/hello-from-csharp.dll --target=framework --platform=iOS --outdir=output -c --debug
```

or with this example from Github > Embeddinator-4000:

```
Use mono ./bin/Debug/objcgen.exe --gen=Obj-C -o ./Output ManagedAssembly1.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My steps to get it to build on a Mac...

1. Clone github > Embeddinator-4000
   git clone https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000.git
2. cd into the cloned dir
3. Install other stuff:
   git submodule update --recursive --init
4. Build objcgen:
   cd objcgen
   make
5. Build the 'wrapper' (ie. command access) to objcgen:
   make nuget